# Android - Java - No Activity Found to Handle Intent

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to create an Android / Java plugin for the cross-platform program Phonegap / Cordova 3.2. I am following several tutorials but can't get the simplest plugin to work.

Currently I am working on the idea that my Java code is just wrong somewhere.

Could someone please review the following code and advise if there is something obviously wrong?

The error I keep getting is

```
Exception: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE dat=file:///{"fullPath":"media\/test.mp3"} }
```

Here is my .java file

```
package org.media.scan;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

public class Scan extends CordovaPlugin {

@Override
public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    try {
        if ( action.equals("addRemove") ) {

            String filePath = args.getString(0);

            filePath = filePath.replaceAll("^file://", "");

            if (filePath.equals("")) {
                callbackContext.error("null path passed");
                return false;
            }               

            File file = new File(filePath);

            Intent scanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
            scanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));

            this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity( scanIntent );
            callbackContext.success("good");
            return true;

        } else {
            callbackContext.error("invalid action phrase");

        }

        return false;

    } catch(Exception e) {

        System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        callbackContext.error(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }




}

}
```

I am calling my Java code with this .js code

```
var Scan = {
createEvent:function (fullPath, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    cordova.exec(
        successCallback, // success callback function
        errorCallback, // error callback function
        'Scan', // mapped to our native Java class
        'addRemove', // with this action name
        [
            {                  
                "fullPath":fullPath
            }
        ]
    );
}
}

module.exports = Scan;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a broadcast action not activity action, you should use the send broadcast method for this kind of action!

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE

This is the wrong line in code "            this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity( scanIntent );
"

Comment: Thank you Chen ! That fixed the code and it is returning success now. However, the media scan doesn't seem to work as it is not showing up as available to the user through the system. I have confirmed the file is in the system folder, but it will only appear if I restart the phone. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://androidyue.github.io/blog/2014/01/19/scan-media-files-in-android/  take a look at this post. I think it could resolve your problem.